# Convert my given ISO date to required format along with timezone name

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I have ISO timezone string say "2019-11-08T14:44:12+0530"

I need it to convert into

08-11-2019 14:44:12 GMT+0530 (IST)

with or without moment?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ["documentation"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: var dataSrt = '2019-11-08T14:44:12+0530';
var result = (new Date(dataSrt));

Answer (score 0):

You can use Moment JS to format the date like this

```
moment(new Date()).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss Z")

//08-11-2019 15:43:30 +05:30
```

Please use this Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Ayyub/6zv2wkgo/19/

Comment: I also needs to know if its IST or PST or any other

Comment: Please include moment-timezone-with-data.min.js & moment-timezone.min.js and use this `moment(new Date()).tz(moment.tz.guess()).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]Z (z)')` I have updated the fiddle link as well

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know the time zone. With that example, you only have the offset (+0530). For example, you can use the time zone "Asia/Calcutta".

Using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) and [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/), you can use this:

```
moment('2019-11-08T14:44:12+0530').tz("Asia/Calcutta").format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]Z (z)');
```

The output will be `"08-11-2019 14:44:12 GMT+05:30 (IST)"`

If you want to use the user's time zone, you can use `moment.tz.guess()`.

```
moment('2019-11-08T14:44:12+0530').tz(moment.tz.guess()).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]Z (z)');
```

In my case, the output will be `"08-11-2019 09:14:12 GMT+00:00 (WET)"`, because i am in a different time zone.